# jQuery append: Dynamic rollover image

Tags: jquery, html, image, razor, rollover

I am working on an asp.net MVC 4 app. I have a details icon that will be placed at the beginning of every dynamically created record. I am to make this image a rollover image. If my thinking is correct I must use html to do this because if I use jquery or css I will run into selection problems because I can't attach an id. This is my code segment for this question:

```
    $('#@tableName > tbody:last').append('<tr>
    <td>
       <a href="#" style="text-decoration:none; float:left;"
       onclick="LoadLaunchDetails(' + launchID + ', @automated)">
       <img  src ="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/icon-details-ns.png")" 
        onmouseover="this.src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/icon-details-s.png")"" 
        onmouseout="this.src="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/icon-details-s.png")""/>
       </a> Launch #' + return_str + '</td><td style = "text-align:right">'+ dateStr + 
    '</td>
    </tr>');
```

The problem I am having is with the quotes in the onmouseover and onmouseout attributes. When I use fire bug I see `onmouseover="this.src="` I have tried many different ways. Is this even possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
src ="@Url.Content("~/Content/images/buttons/icon-details-ns.png")"
```

src is `@Url.Content(`

Errors start here. You must escape your code properly using backslashes.